# xml well formed rules- does an xml document must have an xml declaration

Tags: xml, well-formed, xml-declaration

I was going through the rules of making an xml document well-formed, and didn't understand one thing,
does a xml document must start with the xml declaration in order to be well formed?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Try to remove the xml declaration e. g. in this validator: [w3schools xml validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).